# My VIM basic imap mappings have no effect

Tags: vim, vimrc, keymap

Good afternoon,

I am struggling with Vim mappings. I would like to practice over very basic ones such as "replace **a**-s with **b**-s", or "replace **ù** with **/**", but I do not succeed.

Here are my trials:

```
:imap a b
:imap ù /
:imap 'ù' /
:imap 'ù' '/'
```

Anytime I get into the insertion mode I have **a**-s when I press **a**-s, and **ù**-s when I press **ù**-s.
(Besides this I have more complex mappings correctly working, such as `nnoremap ,<space> :nohlsearch<CR>` or `nnoremap <C-H> <C-W><C-H>`.)

I am running the following version of Vim:
`VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jun 06 2019 17:31:41)`

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first two forms are correct; there's no quoting involved in mappings. You have to use [`:help key-notation`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#key-notation) for certain special keys, though.

If `:imap a b` does not have any effect in insert mode, something's wrong. My best guess would be that you accidentally have `:set paste`; this mode is meant for literal pasting and so insert-mode mappings are disabled. You can check with `:set paste?` and `:set nopaste` would turn this off (for the current session; you'd need to find out in which file (e.g. `.vimrc` or a plugin) this was set.

If it's not [`'paste'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27paste%27), there may be other misconfigurations that cause this. To continue with your (rather simple) experiments, you can start a plain Vim session with `vim --clean`; this ignores any configuration and then the `:imap` should definitely work!

Comment: Thanks… a… lot. I had set `paste`. Actually I often do so for pasting. Now I will unset it afterwards!
Reading the documentation you provided I also see that it solves the abbreviations "not working" !

Comment: The `'pastetoggle'` option is helpful for quicky changing its value via a key. (You obviously cannot use mappings for that). If you closely observe the lower-left corner, you'll see `-- INSERT (paste) --` when this is enabled. If you need a bigger hint, you could also include the paste value in a custom `'statusline'`.